# How can I add more axes of symmetry?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

I try to make this building, which has 10 pillars. So every pillar has to be connected with another at an angle of 36°. With the normal mirror modifier I would only be able to create 4 pillars. 
Also I have no idea how to do this cupola in a proper way. If you have suggestions I would be very grateful.
[image: ***enter image description here***]

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use the "object offset" option in the Array modifier.

1. Create your pillar/section of the cupola
2. Apply Rotation & Scale (or move the origin of the cupola to the origin of your scene)

[image]

3. Create an Empty at the origin

[image]

4. Add an Array modifier to your cupola section, select the "Object Offset" checkbox, and choose the Empty

[image]

5. Enter the number of times to repeat your object (in this case I chose 10)

[image]

6. Select the Empty and rotate it 360 degrees divided by the number of items.  In my example, since I want 10 copies, I rotate the empty by 36 degrees (360/10).  If you wanted a half-circle, you could use 180.

[image]

If you get weird offsets, make sure the object you want to repeat has no rotation or scale on it.  Then, you can control rotation, scale, and offset via the Empty.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to construct this framework:

- Extrude <kbd>E</kbd> the base of a 20-sided hemisphere to shape the basic form.
- Duplicate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> 1 top-to bottom face-loop from it, on one side of the X axis, and <kbd>P</kbd> Part it into a new object.
- (Subdivide the original form, to make it into a good shrinkwrap target)
- Assign a Mirror modifier to the newly created section object in X, and then assign an object-offset Array modifier to it, controlled by an empty at the origin, rotated in Z by 36 degrees.
- If making a starting framework like the one illustrated, you could also assign a Shrinkwrap modifier, with the original form as target.

Now any edit you make to the section will be appropriately reproduced around your cupola.

If you decide to bring in / create other objects as parts during construction, you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> link their modifiers to the section's, to give them to the same style of duplication. (In some parts, you may want to apply the mirror.. in others, drop the Shrinkwrap, it all depends)

This edge-only framework was made by extruding from a single vertex, with a Subdivision Surface modifier assigned just above the Shrinkwrap, and Snap switched on to Face, a little like the standard (no add-on) procedure in *retoplology*, which you could have a look at, if you don't know it already. The purple Form object is not part of the framework, just there to make it easier to see.

[image]

To proceed from here you could use parts of the framework in many ways to make components: convert to Curve and bevel/extrude , a Skin modifier in parts, creating faces, insetting, deleting the insides and solidifying.. maybe different ways will be better for different parts.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do is with the array modifier and the curve modifier:

- create a curve circle
- put the object you wish to replicate around the edge of the circle
- add the array modifier and the curve modifier to the object you wish to replicate
- in the curve modifier select the cricle
- adjust the length of the array to your liking

the example is made in blender 2.8 but it works the same in the previous versions

[image]